# How to import large JSON datasets to Cloud Firestore periodically?

Tags: json, firebase, flutter, parsing, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to import JSON with 180k records. As you can see in this code, I can upload 500 records per run, but I need to upload a 180k record periodically.

**What I am trying To Achieve:**

1. Parse JSON (DONE).
2. Create a model from each JSON element (DONE)
3. Upload this to Cloud Firestore (DONE BUT 500 DOCUMENT EACH)

**Factory of Model:**

```
factory Academician.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Academician(
        // Using this to parse data from JSON, 
        // rating and reviewList does not exist in JSON, 
        // that's why i need custom model 
        name: json["name"] ?? "",
        designation: json["designation"] ?? "",
        field: json["field"] ?? "",
        universityName: json["university"] ?? "",
        department: json["department"] ?? "",
        rating: 0,
        reviewList: [],
      );
```

**Parsing and uploading to Cloud Firestore:**

```
parseJsonFromAssets('json/akademik_kadro.json')
        .then((value) => value['Sayfa1'].forEach((value) {
              academicianList.add(Academician.fromJson(value));
            }))
        .then((value) {
            setState(() {
                for (int z = 0; z < 500; z++) {
                    //500 is the single time upload limit to Cloud Firestore 
                    //I guess
                    dbOperation.addToCollection(academicianList[z]);
            }
          });
        });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You appear to have hit the [writes and transactions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#writes_and_transactions) limit of 500.

| Limit | Details |
| --- | --- |
| Maximum API request size | 10 MiB |
| Maximum number of writes that can be passed to a Commit operation or performed in a transaction | 500 |
| Maximum number of field transformations that can be performed on a single document in a Commit operation or in a transaction | 500 |

A better way to do this is using [Batched writes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes).

> A batched write can contain up to 500 operations. Each operation in the batch counts separately towards your Cloud Firestore usage. Within a write operation, field transforms like `serverTimestamp`, `arrayUnion`, and increment each count as an additional operation.

You can structure your directories something like this:

```
batch_uploader\
    json_files\
        json_1.json   
        json_1.json
        json_1.json 
        json_1.json
    uploader.js
    ....
```

`uploader.js`

```js
var admin = require("firebase-admin");

var serviceAccount = require("./service_key.json");

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "YOUR_PROJECT_LINK"
});

const firestore = admin.firestore();
const path = require("path");
const fs = require("fs");
const directoryPath = path.join(__dirname, "files");

fs.readdir(directoryPath, function(err, files) {
  if (err) {
    return console.log("Unable to scan directory: " + err);
  }

  files.forEach(function(file) {
    var lastDotIndex = file.lastIndexOf(".");

    var menu = require("./json_files/" + file);

    menu.forEach(function(obj) {
      firestore
        .collection(file.substring(0, lastDotIndex))
        .doc(obj.itemID)
        .set(obj)
        .then(function(docRef) {
          console.log("Document written");
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
        });
    });
  });
});
```

If you want to run the script periodically, you can [schedule a function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions#write_a_scheduled_function) to run at specified times. To run the script every five minutes, for example, you can do something like this:

```
exports.scheduledFunction = functions.pubsub.schedule('every 5 minutes').onRun((context) => {
  console.log('This will be run every 5 minutes!');
  return null;
});
```

Comment: So, i have to use cloud functions for this?

Comment: If you want to schedule the import then yes.